# Error tesseract qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt, tesseract, leptonica

I have a strange error. 
I want to build a simple example.

.pro file:

```
... 

LIBS += ... -llept
LIBS += ... -ltesseract
```

main.cpp:

```
char *outText;

tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
// Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying tessdata path
if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
    exit(1);
}

// Open input image with leptonica library
Pix *image = pixRead("/usr/src/tesseract-3.02/phototest.tif");
api->SetImage(image);
// Get OCR result
outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
printf("OCR output:\n%s", outText);

// Destroy used object and release memory
api->End();
delete [] outText;
pixDestroy(&image);

return 0;
```

error:

> .../liblept.a(zlibmem.o): undefined reference to symbol 'deflate' error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line  collect2: error: Ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: undefined `deflate` sounds like missing zlib. Do you link in `-lz` ?

Comment: Thx it's resolved my problem!!

Answer (score -1):

You have to add the source files (.cpp) to the .pro file.

[Similar problem](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/56441-How-to-use-external-source-code-in-Qt-creator)

Comment: Probably not. Sounds more like missing library in path.